# Membership Provider - only connect to default provider?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my web config I have 2 membership providers defined, one for sql, one for active directory.  My thought process was that on a release build, I set AD as the default, but while debugging I use sql.  This is because my dev computer does not have access to the domain to authenticate users.

It seems to me however that my web site tries to connect to both sources instead of just the default provider.  So while I have an active directory provider defined, I cannot do development because it fails to connect, even though sql is defined as default.

Is there a way to only connect to the default provider?

My currently broken web config is like so:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SqlServer" />
    <add name="ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ActiveDirectoryServer" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>

  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Are you oppose to naming them both "MembershipProvider" and then commenting out the un-necessary one?  <!--add ..... -->

Comment: Thats what I currently do to deploy.  But this is less than ideal..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web.release.config file, you can just swap out the whole membership section with the AD information and in the web.config you can leave it as it or only have the SQL provider.

For the web.release.config:

```
<system.web>
  <membership defaultProvider="ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ActiveDirectoryServer" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using VS2010?

How about using [web.config transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326%28VS.100%29.aspx)?

There is also an [interesting article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx) in Scott Guthrie's blog.

Comment: Im currently using transformations to change the default provider on a release build, but I do not know if its possible to add a whole new provider while deleting the other.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `web.config` add default provider:

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" 
             connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

And inside your `web.Release.config` add a transformation:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" 
         connectionString="Data Source=ReleaseSQLServer;Initial Catalog=MyReleaseDB;Integrated Security=True"  
         xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**NOTE:**

Changing the build configuration doesn't trigger the transformation it works only when you publish your web site.

To test it you don't have to do this on production server, you can publish to file system.